# How to get default gray color of UISearchBar

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, bartintcolor

My layout places the `UISearchController`'s search bar as a subview of my table view header, alongside other custom controls (buttons, etc.).

In order to make all the controls inside the header view to "blend in", I want to set the header view's background color to match that of the search bar (that is, the outer rim's light gray, **not** the input textfield's white).

I've tried querying both the search bar's `backgroundColor` and `barTintColor` propErties in `viewDidLoad()`, but both return `nil`, and my header view ends up **white**.

I *could* hard code the color (ColorPicker reports it to be `RGB (199, 199, 204)`, at least on the Simulator), but that's not an elegant solution and will break one day when Apple changes the appearance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The background for the search bar is actually an image so you cannot retrieve it's background color. However, if you just want it to blend in then you can change the imageView to be transparent and set the background color to anything you wish. The UIImageView was found to be here using the view debugger in Xcode.

In Swift 2.0

```
(searchBar.subviews[0].subviews[0] as! UIImageView).alpha = 0
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. This answers my question, but unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem: relying on what is likely the private implementation of the search bar's internal view layout is as likely to break in the future as it is hard coding the background color. I guess I'll have to chose the lesser evil...